# Adding a webform to a different content type

Tags: forms, nodes, webforms

I have an "event" content type.  Now I want to add a Webform to it so that people can request purchasing and availability information.

I checked my event content type in `admin/config/content/webform` under `Webform-enabled content types` but how can I now add the form to my existing content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webform is empty. You need add some fields to the webform.
You can add webform to any "event" node.
Try this: go to your_host/node/node_id/webform and you can see wizard for webform elements!